# Threadlocal for initialise a variable in java web project

Tags: java, servlets

I want to intialise a variable for a `HttpServletRequest`. for that i want to check if the request have already intialise the variable or not. am using `tomcat` server

for example: 
A `HttpServletRequest` has so much `DBoperations` to be performed. so can i use one `connection` for the entire `HttpServletRequest`. also allocate different connections for different request. can i perform this by using `Threadlocal` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do that. Java web servers like Tomcat or Jetty are thread pooled servers, which means each `HttpServletRequest` is handled by a thread from the server thread pool.

When working with database connections, there are two common patterns being applied: connection-per-operation and connection-per-request/thread. The latter is prefered and recommended, and `ThreadLocal` is used to implement, each thread owns a connection to perform a series of operations.

In fact, framework like Hibernate use `ThreadLocal` (`ThreadLocalSessionContext`) to implement connection/session-per-request/thread. 
You can read more from here http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-threads3/.

Update:
You just create a connection and store it in a shared ThreadLocal object, then you get the connection (not shared with other threads) from this to use for all operations within a thread/request as in 'Listing 3" from the link above.
Hope this helps!